# Getting a 404 for css in Express

Tags: javascript, html, css, express

My folder structure is something like this:

- app

  - controller
  - routes
  - app.js

Within my controller folder, I have

- controller

  - sites folder

    - index.html
    - style.css
  - controller.js

Here is my Controller.js

```js
const express = require('express');

app = express();
app.use(express.static('../site'));
module.exports= {

  index : (req, res, next)=>{
    res.status(200);
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '\\site\\index.html');
  }
};
```

And here is my index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Template</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

When I run the server and do a GET request, Express gives a 404 on the CSS file. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: CSS file is named `styles.css`, not `style.css`. You missed 's' at the end of 'style'.

Comment: Sorry about that, that was a mistake on my part while writing the question, The css file is style.css in folder and in the html link. It still doesn't work.